# Notation (manifolds, harmonic analysis)

Tags: notation, manifolds

I was reading the paper [*"On the Multilinear Restriction and Kakeya conjectures"*](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0509262v1.pdf) by Bennett, Carbery and Tao

For each $1\leq j\leq n$ let $U_j$ be a compact neighborhood of the origin in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ and $\,\Sigma_j:U_j\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be a smooth parametrization of a $(n-1)$-dimensional submanifold.
Define
$$
Y_j(x):= \bigwedge_{k=1}^{n-1} \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_k} \,\Sigma_j(x)
$$

My question is:

> What does $\wedge$ mean in this case? In the paper, they say one can view $Y_j$ as a vector field.

Comment: This is a [wedge product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra).

Comment: As is mentioned in the paper, strictly speaking $Y_j$ is an $(n-1)$-form.  It is then said that *by duality*, one can view $Y_j$ as a vector field.

Answer (score 2):

This is a long comment. Suppose that $n=3$, so what does it mean $\frac{\partial\Sigma}{\partial x_1}\wedge \frac{\partial\Sigma}{\partial x_2}$? This is a 2-form, but by $\textit{duality}$ you can see it as a vector, the cross product, which is normal to the surface. Just the same for higher dimensions, you have a $(n-1)$-form, that consists of $n$ components, by $\textit{duality}$ or $\textit{Hodge star operator}$, you can look at these components as a vector.

Good luck!